# mySql calculate sum of date difference

Tags: mysql

I am developing a employee login system in which user check in and checkout timings are recorder. I have the following mySql table schema from which I would like to query the total working hours of an employee of a particular month.

```
AttendanceId    UserId  Operation   CreatedDate
24                 4       1       2016-03-20 23:18:59
25                 4       2       2016-03-20 23:19:50
26                 4       1       2016-03-20 23:20:28
27                 4       2       2016-03-20 23:20:31
```

Operation 1 is for check in and operation 2 is for checkout. Can any one help me to build this query?

Comment: What if an employee checks in on the 31st and checks out on the 1st?

Comment: @Strawberry i forgot that thing.Can you suggest an idea or better schema for the same?

Comment: Just answer the question. Or don't. It's up to you.

Comment: @SirajEA Create a table that includes all relevant data. It may/should include columns like `id`, `user_id`, `date`, `time_in`, `time_out`, and `total_hrs`. With those columns, you can create a query with specific date, employees w/o time-in or time-out, total of working hrs in a day, etc.

Comment: I do not consider rhavendc's approach to be an improvement on what you have currently.

Comment: @Strawberry Oh, sorry. I think you're right. I'm such an evil.

Answer (score 0):

A pleasingly complicated question, thanks. My query deals with:

- Attendances that aren't precisely measured in hours. The number of seconds is totalled and divided by 3600 at the end of the calculation.
- Attendances that span the month boundary at either end (thanks [strawberry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1529673/strawberry))
- Attendances in the current month that have started (there is an entry with operation "1") but not yet finished (there is no corresponding operation "2").

I used the following data for testing:

```
INSERT INTO Attendance(UserId, Operation, CreatedDate) VALUES
(4, 1, '2016-01-01 15:00:00'),
(4, 2, '2016-01-01 19:00:00'),
(4, 1, '2016-01-31 23:00:00'),
(4, 2, '2016-02-01 01:00:00'),
(4, 1, '2016-02-20 23:18:59'),
(4, 2, '2016-02-20 23:19:50'),
(4, 1, '2016-02-20 23:20:28'),
(4, 2, '2016-02-20 23:20:31'),
(4, 1, '2016-02-29 23:00:00'),
(4, 2, '2016-03-01 01:00:00'),
(4, 1, '2016-03-02 15:00:00'),
(4, 2, '2016-03-02 18:00:00'),
(4, 1, '2016-03-22 10:00:00');
```

The query selects all users' hours for a specific month. Selecting results for more than one month in one query is more complicated because of the possibility that attendances span month boundaries and if required it might be simplest to iterate over the months and run the query repeatedly, adjusting the four dates in the SQL appropriately.

The innermost query selects all arrival times and the corresponding departure time for all users. The outer query then restricts them to the current month, calculates the difference between the two times, and sums them by user.

```
SELECT UserId, SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(
    SECOND,
    GREATEST(TimeIn, '2016-02-01'),
    LEAST(COALESCE(TimeOut, NOW()), '2016-03-01'))) / 3600 HoursInMonth
FROM (SELECT TimeIn.UserId, TimeIn.CreatedDate TimeIn, MIN(TimeOut.CreatedDate) TimeOut
      FROM Attendance TimeIn
      LEFT JOIN Attendance TimeOut ON TimeOut.UserId = TimeIn.UserId
                                  AND TimeOut.Operation = 2
                                  AND TimeOut.CreatedDate > TimeIn.CreatedDate
      WHERE TimeIn.operation = 1
      GROUP BY TimeIn.AttendanceId
      ORDER BY TimeIn.CreatedDate) TimeInOut
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(TimeIn,  '%Y-%m') = '2016-02'
   OR DATE_FORMAT(TimeOut, '%Y-%m') = '2016-02'
   OR (DATE_FORMAT(TimeIn, '%Y-%m') < '2016-02' AND TimeOut IS NULL)
GROUP BY UserId;
```